# How to turn a text into a column - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, excel, pdf, pdfplumber

I am new to pandas.
I have a PDF data table which I read and extract the data from, converting it into an Excel file.
This is a short, fictitious example of the table I am using, however the structure of the PDF is exactly the same:

[table.pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Axr2d.png)

After converting the PDF to Excel, I get this: The table is complete and the conversion was successfully completed.
[excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVOXj.png)

Notice that each word within the single quotes, are a column within my original PDF. The commas, are some empty columns that are in the PDF.

I would like to know how I can turn those words into columns again, using pandas?
I want to get a result similar to this:
[final excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wp4cD.png)

My simple code is below:

```
import pdfplumber
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter

with pdfplumber.open('Sistema BanPara.pdf') as pdf:
    df = pd.DataFrame(page.extract_table() for page in pdf.pages).astype(str)
with pd.ExcelWriter('table.xlsx') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer)
```

Comment: Can you try `df = pd.concat(pd.DataFrame(page.extract_table()) for page in pdf.pages)` instead? Currently you're passing all the tables at once to a single `pd.DataFrame()` call which is why you're ending up with nested lists.

Comment: Rather than processing via Excel see [link](https://pypi.org/project/tabula-py/) for a module that forms Pandas DFs direct from PDF files.